# Using a code used to get a range with a different column

Tags: vba, excel

my question is quite simple. In the project i'm currently working on I want to do an operation on the range like `p2:q600` but the the case is not always `p2:q600`. 
The cells on `p2:q600` include some empty cells so i can not use `Sheets("Stock").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` , my question is, how can i get the number of rows from the A or B column to use with the range to get my operation done.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the last row with data? This will be determined by your data layout. If you are, see the following to help: [Find last row, column or last cell](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) For example, can you swop the Q  in Sheets("Stock").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row for an A? i.e. Sheets("Stock").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ?

Comment: I believe the confusion here arises from my lack of explanation. The bottom line of my problem is this. I can use ´Sheets("Stock").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row´ because A is the list of  code of products but the row Q is filled up by employees and it is quite messy, some of them are empty and some of them are not. That is why i can not use ´Sheets("Stock").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row´ and what i want is just get the number from the product number from the list at column A to make the operation with that number at column Q. I hope my explanation helped.

Comment: Sounds like use column A to determine last row and either have an isempty test or perhaps wrap in an iferror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
dim lr as long, rng as range

with worksheets("sheet1")

    lr = application.max(.cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row, _
                         .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup).row)

    set rng = .range(.cells(2, "P"), .cells(lr, "Q"))
    debug.print rng.address(0, 0)

end with
```

Another common method is to

```
lr = .range("A:B").find(what:="*", after:=.cells(1), _
                        searchorder:=xlbyrows, searchdirection:=xlprevious).row
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 set rng = Intersect(Range("P:Q"), Range("P2").CurrentRegion`)
```

Depending on your data, it could do the trick.